Maven assembly:single fails with "Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found." unless I specify an executionId
Suppose I have a maven project which has this plugins section in its pom:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <formats>
                        <format>zip</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scripts-package</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/script.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                   <execution>
                        <id>rest-runtime-scripts-secondary-package</id>
                        <phase>secondary-generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>computeClasspath.sh</include>
                            </includes>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/script.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tempscript</outputDirectory>
                            <formats>
                                <format>dir</format>
                            </formats>
                            <ignoreDirFormatExtensions>true</ignoreDirFormatExtensions>
                            <attach>false</attach>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

If I run on it mvn package, the zips are generated successfully. However, when I run mvn jar:jar jar:test-jar assembly:single, the execution fails with the following error:
Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.
However, if I specify the execution id like this: mvn jar:jar jar:test-jar assembly:single@generate-scripts-package, the zips of that execution are generated. However, I want a way to generate all the zips without specifying the execution id.
How can I do that?
P.S.: Note that I can't use mvn package for performance issues and I can't specify the execution id because I am running this command mvn jar:jar jar:test-jar assembly:single from the parent pom.

What does that mean: Note that I can't use mvn package for performance issues .. using the life cycle is the solution... simple and easy....

Hello @khmarbaise, I currently do just what u suggested, but the reason I want to switch to doing mvn jar:jar jar:test-jar assembly:single install:install -DskipTests instead of mvn package is for performance optimization. mvn package takes 7min, and I want to reduce it as much as possible. By doing mvn jar:jar jar:test-jar alone I was able to reduce it to 3min.

Note that when I do mvn assembly:single it throws the error I mentioned. But when I do mvn assembly:single@executionId, it works. I just want a way for assembly:single to execution all the executions.
